# In a list of tuples, how do we get 2nd element

Tags: python

Given a list of tuple:

```
data = [('David', '5239980'), ('Bob', '4562345'), ('Jenny', '2541273')]
```

What is the easiest way of getting the 2nd element?
 E.g. if I want to get the corresponding number value to David or Bob?

Comment: Converting to a dict and using a key lookup is pretty _easy_: `d = dict(data); d['David']`

Answer (score 0):

I use python list comprehension

```
[y for x, y in data if (x == 'David' or x == 'Bob')]
```

Comment: Could you explain the y for x part? A bit new and having a bit of trouble understanding it

Comment: Let me be a bit more explicit:
[y for (x,y) in data if (x=='David' or x == 'Bob')]

Comment: from: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: 5.1.3. List Comprehensions
List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of some operations applied to each member of another sequence or iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a certain condition.